# How can we remove the Work tab from the Samsung all-apps screen after the Profile is removed?

Tags: samsung

I have a Samsung SN9600 (international Note 10).

I recently left a job that pushed a Work Profile to the phone.

The Work Profile was locked by the employer, as it should be.  I found the settings to Delete the Profile, and also did my best to Delete or Disable any Work Profile apps.

- Now I want to remove the Work tab in the screen of all apps.
  .
  .
  .

[image]

.
.
.
 - **Any ideas about how to remove this Work tab?**

Comment: hah!  I've stumped you ;-p

Comment: Did you ever figure out the answer to this? I am in the same boat now.

Comment: no, not at all, unfortunately.  It doesn't seem to be a hot topic

Comment: @KarminWehr -- it looks like it can uninstall properly now.   I can't recall the screens from a year ago to say if they changed, but the answer added worked for me now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn on the Work Profile.
Next select Accounts and remove your old work account. (May not be needed)
Next select Uninstall Work Profile.

I did it so fast but I believe that was all the steps I took.

Comment: nice :)  If I had that option a year ago, it didn't remove the panel, and for sure noone online talked about it.  Right now I'm Android 10 and Samsung OneUI 2.1 and this worked.   After turning back on Work Profile, now there was an Uninstall option at the bottom and it does seem to have removed the panel.